# math with very small numbers using float and double

Tags: c++, c, double, physics

I'm writing this code just to see the difference in the precision value while using a float and a double.
basically I'm trying to calculate the value of reduced Plancks constant.
Reduced Plancks const = Plancks const/2π.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

const float H = 6.62607015e-34;
const float Pi = 3.1415926;
int main()
{
    float a = H / (2 * Pi);
    double b = H / (2 * Pi);
    printf("float is %ld \ndouble is %ld", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

But the output does not make sense at all. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
float is 536870912
double is 954303911
```

I even tried to change the datatypes of the constants to double, which was no better.

```
float is 0
double is 954303911
```

I decreased the significant digits in the constant but it made no difference.
Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `%ld` is used for `integers` not for `float` or `double`, use `%E` for scientific notation.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings

Comment: @GauravDhiman Thanks didn't know about %E. But %ld worked for float and double whenever I included math.h .

Comment: @ShreyasPatil: `%ld` does not work for `float` or `double` regardless of whether you include `math.h` or not. If you thought it did, you were fooled by some coincidence of circumstances or you fooled yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%ld` is supposed to get a `long int` as argument, not double. Try `%f`, `%e`, `%g`, with additional modifiers at your option, or other formats supported by  [`printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Moreover, you should consider enabling compiler warnings, for example `-W -Wall` with gcc:

```
: In function 'main':
:10:5: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
     printf("float is %ld \ndouble is %ld", a, b);
     ^
:10:5: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
```

The arguments have type `double` because `float` is promoted when used with a varargs function like `printf`.

In your example, the computations are basically the same: both `H / (2 * Pi)` computation are carried out as float, and  after that the result is converted to `double`: in one case because `b` is `double` and in the other case due to promotion rules for `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("float is %ld \ndouble is %ld", a, b);
```

`%d` is the format specifier for integers, not floats. Use `%f` instead, it will work for `double` and because of automatic argument promotion, `%f` works also for `float`.

Most compilers would give a warning of this kind of error. Make sure you have warnings enabled in your compiler. For GCC, use `-Wall -Wextra`.